# How can I capture the position of the data in cytoscape when the user drag and free the nodes?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am able to restore the node position using sessionStorage, however, if users drag and free the nodes, I want to overwrite that to the sessionStorage and restore the latest one that has been adjusted by the user. Any idea how can I capture that node position when it is drag and free? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use `drag` or `dragfree` events https://js.cytoscape.org/#events/collection-events

Comment: Will try and do so. Thank you!!!

Comment: @canbax, I implemented dragfree and now it is working perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.